# Downloading Files from FTP server which is updated in last n hours

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

My requirement is to download the files which are arrived in the root directory in the last 24 hours.

The code below is working in a subdirectory (let's say ftp.cwd("/Landing/") but trigger the error while I am changing to the root directory.

```
filematch='*.csv'
ftp.cwd("/")
for file_data in ftp.mlsd(filematch):
    file_name,meta = file_data
    last_modified = datetime.strptime(meta.get("modify"), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    
    if (last_modified) >= now- timedelta(hours=0, minutes=1440):                   
        print(last_modified)
        local_filename = os.path.join('C:\\Work\\', file_name)
        file = open(local_filename, 'wb')
        with open(local_filename, "wb") as file:
            ftp.retrbinary(f"RETR {file_name}", file.write)
```

If I'am changing the `>=` to `==` then its working in root directory ( but both condition are fine in subdirectory; issue is only in root)

`if (last_modified) = now- timedelta(hours=0, minutes=1440):`

**Error Message:-**

File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ftplib.py", line 425, in retrbinary    with self.transfercmd(cmd, rest) as conn:  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ftplib.py", line 382, in transfercmd    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ftplib.py", line 348, in ntransfercmd    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ftplib.py", line 275, in sendcmd    return self.getresp()  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ftplib.py", line 248, in getresp    raise error_perm(resp)**ftplib.error_perm: 550 Permission denied.**

Comment: "Permission denied" means you are not allowed to read that directory.

Comment: Hi, I am able to download the files when I put  if (last_modified) == now- timedelta(hours=0, minutes=1440): but when I put ">=" instead of == then only getting the permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed.

root cause:-

1>

```
filematch='*.csv'
ftp.cwd("/")
for file_data in ftp.mlsd(filematch):
```

above code will fetch list of everything in spite putting file type as csv.

Note ** LIST() does not work in FTP

once list and directory will be available then it will try to write the files using retrbinanary and it will support only files not dir

```
ftp.retrbinary(f"RETR {file_name}", file.write)
```

so just put one more condition in if statement and pick only the file.

```
Condition meta([type])=="file"
```